# Laravel Vuejs bootstrap-table-vue jsPDF is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-table, tableexportjs

I kept getting this error when I click the pdf format button of bootstrap table for Vue

```
app.js:100649 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
    at jQuery.fn.init../node_modules/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js.d.fn.tableExport
```

after installing bootstrap-table and table export to my laravel vue application.
I have in my app.js

```
require('bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css');
//
require('tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/print/bootstrap-table-print.min.js');
//
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.css');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js');
```

and my vue contains

```
    <bootstrap-table  
            data-search="true"
            data-filter-control="true"
            data-show-export="true"
            data-pagination="true"
            data-side-pagination="server"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar"
            data-show-toggle="true"
            data-show-columns="true"
            data-export-types="['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf']"
            :data="showOrders"
                         :columns="displayColumns"></bootstrap-table>
```

I checked a number of other questions here and none seems to be related to this Laravel Vue version of jsPDF error I'm experiencing. Besides, all other exported formats are working fine except when I click on pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min');
```

must be

```
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js');
```